# Can a sinner attain liberation and avoid hell just through bhakti?

Tags: philosophy

I saw a picture of an elephant being saved from a crocodile by Vishnu. The caption read that the elephant was supposed to represent humans, and the crocodile was meant to be the hardships (punishments) due to bad karma, and it represented Vishnu saving his devotees from their bad karma. Does that mean that just Bhakti can annul punishment?

On the other hand, this does not make sense to me. Hurting others must have some punishment even if you are a great devotee of God. Otherwise, all evil people can save themselves just through bhakti, while avoiding punishments for their wrong acts.

Comment: If you’re a great devotee of god the nature of committing sins vanishes automatically. You won’t remain a sinner if you’re a true devotee at heart.

Comment: Only after you have suffered through your complete prarabdha, any liberation will be possible. The balance of positive and negative karmas must be 0

Comment: What is prarabdha @Vivikta

Comment: Prarabdha (ordained) is destiny/fate which arises for your present birth on account of the accumulated (sanchit karmas) from the sum total of all the previous birth your jeeva underwent in the *karma-based yonis*

Comment: How to balance positive and negative karmas perfectly? @vivikta

Comment: Only *Ishvara* can help in that regard, imo. Somewhere I heard - *""मुक्ति हमारे हाथ में होती है, लेकिन मोक्ष हमेशा ईश्वर के हाथ में"* - (Liberation (realization) is in our hands, but the ultimate Moksha is only in the hands of the Supreme). & one can't balance by themselves, one has to realize the concept then the future karmas and fruits ceases. What has already been sown as karmic seeds will always bear the prarabdha fruits until anything from past karmic balance is over.